# Adding a subview behaves different in ad-hoc distribution

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

This one is a weird one. I have a more complex application that I will not detail here, but one of it's features is that it overlays a translucent black view on top of everything each time a connection is made to the server.

I add that view like this:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)app.delegate;
[appDelegate.window addSubview:http.progressView.view];
```

When I run it on the simulator or on device, everything works well: the black screen overlays everything else as expected.

The weird part is this: I archive the application, pack it as an .ipa file and then install it on the phone using itunes (or TestFlight). When I do this, in some places, the black overlay is offseted to the top-right of the screen with about 10 pixels, like the `frame.origin.x` will be 10 and `frame.origin.y` will be -10.

Does anybody know what may differ when building the applications as .ipa that makes it behave so differently. I'm afraid of this not happening also when I'll build it for deployment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that it'll be built with release settings during archive (e.g. optimisation level `s` usually, vs optimisation level `0` for debug).

You're not setting the frame of `http.progressView.view` which is likely causing the problems. Set it to be the `applicationFrame` of the window's `UIScreen`:

```
http.progressView.view.frame = appDelegate.window.screen.applicationFrame;
```

Comment: OMG! It actually worked :)). I was having low hopes for solving this. Thank you a bunch !!!

Comment: For whom may care, here is the code translation of what matt said above: add the following code before adding the subview: http.progressView.view.frame = appDelegate.window.screen.applicationFrame;

Comment: @NicolaeSurdu - added that to my answer.